# Can Java Applet Code Be Seen?

Tags: java, html, browser, applet

If I embed a Java applet in a browser, is there any way that the Java code can be seen on the client side?

Using HTML5, if the code can't be seen with a simple "Inspect Element," its source can eventually be retrieved.

If a Java applet is used, is the client-code absolutely hidden?

Comment: The client can only access the bytecode. (Btw applets are a long dead technology)

Comment: @4castle Thanks for the input, I was just playing around with them because they were the first thing that came to mind when I thought about making a browser application's code completely invisible for fun; I'm not actually planning to use them for anything serious, the security concerns are a nightmare

Comment: @stackptr It would be great if you could link to one of those sources!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](http://www.webliminal.com/Lrn-web-appendixe.html):

> The programs are first written in Java, compiled or translated to byte codes using a Java compiler, and when a Web browser retrieves a page with the Applet tag, the byte codes are sent to the computer viewing the Web page to be executed there.

That means you can see only the byte code, but not the Java source code.

Comment: That said, decompilers can often do a good job of turning that bytecode back into readable java.

Comment: @yshavit Too true. An applet is **completely unsuited** to 'hiding the code' (ultimate goal as later explained by the OP).

Answer (score 1):

> ..making a browser application's code completely invisible..

The only potential way to do that is to move the functionality to the server side, and only feed the end result to the User Agent (AKA browser).

As mentioned by others, the byte codes of an applet are trivial to reverse engineer.